# Calculating Base Resistor in Transistor

Tags: transistors

I have a question regarding the base resistor value for a transistor. I am already familiar with finding this value (using the min hfe value and using Ohms law to find the desired resistance) but I was wondering if it was also necessary to multiply the base current by the MAX hfe value to ensure that it does not exceed the transistors maximum collector current rating? Is this necessary to do, or does the transistor have a way of regulating itself when the collector current is above its max? Thanks!

Comment: Show a circuit that you might be considering because not all circuits use a base resistor and there are many circuits so choose one.

Comment: You always have to make sure your circuit is not going to cause the transistor to overheat or fail due to some other violation of an absolute maximum rating from the datasheet. You should also normally make sure that your circuit will not fail during what I would call frequently encountered abnormal conditions. And finally, you should always make sure that failures do not result in harm to people or extreme property damage (like burning down a house) even after a single failure or cascade of failures initiated by a single failure. If you want more specifics, post a circuit!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean some common-emitter BJT circuit, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2finbiZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The answer to your question depends on what "some load" is. The collector current can be, at most, whatever the current through "some load" would be if its lower terminal was shorted to ground. In practice it will be a little less, as the collector-emitter voltage probably can't go below 0.2V. This will be specified in the datasheet.

Does that exceed the transistor's maximum collector current rating? If so, you might want to do something about that. Perhaps reduce the maximum current through the load by adding some resistance in series with it, or select a transistor with a higher maximum current rating.

While you *could* limit the maximum collector current by limiting the base current through the proper selection of R1, this is a difficult way to go. hFE varies quite a lot between individual transistors even of the same model, and it also varies by temperature. Datasheets often specify minimum hFE but they do not specify a maximum. And hFE is also quite large, meaning small variations in base current will make large variations in collector current. That means R1 must be very precise and stable over temperature.

So in practice, most designs of circuits like this control the collector current by controlling the load, rather than controlling the base resistor.